# Why does the Pinterest code change the page (URL) displayed in the browser?

Tags: javascript, pinterest

So I have spent a long time trying to find a Pinterest Pin It button that has both a counter AND allows me to choose any image from the page when I click on it.

The Pinterest code supplied by Pinterest requires you to specify a specific image to be shared, but it has a count.

The Pinterest browser button can be adopted to use on a page and will bring up a javascript window allowing the user to choose any suitable image on the page, but it has no count.

I've been playing around and searching and am very close. I have this code which is some of my own and some I've found on other sites:

```
<a class='pin-it-button' count-layout='horizontal' href='http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url={Encoded URL of Current Page}'>Pin It</a>
<a href='javascript:void(run_pinmarklet())' style='margin-left:-93px; width:43px; height:20px; display:inline-block;'/></a>
<script src='http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function run_pinmarklet() {
var e=document.createElement('script');
e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
e.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');
e.setAttribute('src','http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r=' + Math.random()*99999999);
document.body.appendChild(e);
}
</script>
```

What this is doing is basically cheating by having the count button but then putting the code that lets a user choose an image an an element directly on top of the original button. A user thinks he is clicking on the Pin It button but is clicking on an  that runs the javascript run_pinkarklet().

This works, however after I get the pop-over to choose an image, and I do choose the image, it then gets inserted into a pop-up window to complete the pinning, which works- but in the mean time the main page in the browser reloads. It doesn't reload the original page but it reloads the main URL of the current folder.

Example- suppose the page I am pinning is:
    http://www.example.com/folder1/page1.php

It reloads to-
    http://www.example.com/folder1/

I can't find any way to stop this reloading or to get it to at least reload the source page.

I've confirmed this behavior on latest Chrome and Firefox.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well it seems this is happening on many sites now, and it isn't because of the special code- All sites that are using the Pinterest browser button are reloading to their main pages- so Pinterest must have changed something.

Answer (score 0):

[Pinterest's Widget builder](http://business.pinterest.com/en/widget-builder#do_pin_it_button) now supports the any image option.

Answer (score -2):

Set the URL value in to a cookie variable while onclick event.You can access the cookie value,Use the cookie value and redirect the page.

Answer (score -3):

javascript:void((function(){var%20e=document.createElement('script');e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');e.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');e.setAttribute('src','http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r='+Math.random()*99999999);document.body.appendChild(e)})());